# Which algorithm can i use for predicting length of stay in coming year based on historical claims data?

Tags: machine-learning

I have two years historical health claims data of one thousand members. Based on this two years data, I have to predict length of stay in hospital in 3rd year for all members. here is the data sample.

```
Year MembID x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6 x7 LengthOfStay

2010 1 6 35 0 3 0 0 4 1

2010 1 8 35 0 5 0 0 3 0

2009 1 5 35 0 5 0 0 3 3

2009 1 3 35 0 8 2 0 8 0

2010 2 6 30 0 3 3 2 4 0

2010 2 8 30 0 5 0 0 3 0

2009 2 5 30 0 5 0 0 3 0

2010 2 5 30 1 5 0 2 2 0

2009 3 5 55 1 5 1 2 2 0

2010 3 10 55 1 5 0 2 2 0

2010 3 5 55 1 5 1 2 2 0

2009 3 10 55 1 5 0 0 2 0

2010 4 5 24 1 5 0 0 2 0

2009 4 3 24 1 8 0 0 2 0

2009 5 10 65 1 5 1 2 4 5

2009 5 5 65 1 5 0 2 3 0

2010 5 6 65 1 3 0 0 4 1

2010 5 4 65 1 5 0 0 4 0
2010 6 10 44 1 5 1 2 4 5 
2011--- i expect------ 1
```

I did the classification with randomforest. How can I proceed further for prediction on 2011?

Comment: What information do you have on 2011?

Comment: I have memberID and also features.

Comment: Then you can just do the prediction directly. I don't know what's your problem here.

Comment: yes, i can predict using features of 2011 but I want without using features of the year 2011. For example, in given data sample MemberID 5 stay in hospital 5 days in 2009, 0 in 2010 and based on that two year is it possible to predict 2011 for that member?

Comment: Year MembID x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6 x7 LengthOfStay
2010 4 5 24 1 5 0 0 2 0

2009 4 3 24 1 8 0 0 2 0

2009 5 10 65 1 5 1 2 4 5

2009 5 5 65 1 5 0 2 3 0

2010 5 6 65 1 3 0 0 4 1

2010 5 4 65 1 5 0 0 4 0

2010 6 10 44 1 5 1 2 4  5

2011--- i expect------    1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do prediction using 2011 features, the answer is **yes**, you can do that.

However, as you don't want to use these features, the answer might be **no**.

Without using 2011 features, your dataset will have only 2 samples(2009 and 2010) under the assumption that every `memberID` is different. Prediction from two samples is neither reliable nor feasible.

Comment: I don't think he needs the features of 2011 to make predictions for 2011. You predict the future from the past - i.e. use data up to and including 2010 to predict what will happen 2011. A "member" might show first symptoms of some illness in 2010 that might make him go to hospital in 2011.. that doesn't require features of 2011.

Comment: Concerning 2 samples per "member": I think some hierarchical model might work - i.e. first figure out the global influence of features and then per user. For example: "members" who take medicin A (= feature x1) generally spend n days in hospital. Prediction for concrete members: member 1 doesn't take that medicine, member 2 started taking it last year. Who's probably going to spend more time in hospital? - member 2. I'd probably try this with some bayesian model instead of random forests though...

Answer (score 0):

If I'm getting it right,

First of all, since the value you want to predict (days of staying) is a continuous variable, this is a typical **regression** problem, **not classification** and if you follow [sklearn's flowchart](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/machine_learning_map/index.html), you will find the right estimator.

But most important, you have to follow the basic steps:

1. **Understanding the Dataset**

   - Data Exploration
   - Outlier Investigation
2. **Optimize Feature Selection/Engineering**

   - Create new features (if needed - depends on the existing features)
   - Select features
   - Properly scale features
3. **Pick and Tune an Algorithm**

   - Pick an algorithm
   - Tune the algorithm
4. **Validate and Evaluate**

After you have completed the above steps you will have a model able to give it an array of features (e.g. [4, 5, 24, 1, 5, 0, 0, 2]) and it will predict the days of staying. (I skipped the year cause I don't think it will help your prediction. You will find it out on step 2).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this as a truly predictive model, you are going to need *a lot* more information. You are going to need various factors that could have predicted the hospital stay in previous years (gender, age, weight, etc) and then create a cross-validated model for predicting the nights in a hospital for each person. From there you will be able to predict future years.

On the other hand, if you don't have any more information, you might be able to use the Poisson distribution. However, I don't know if the clustered hospital nights (technically they are not singular) would fit the criteria for that distribution.